# Parsing RTF non-breaking space

Tags: parsing, rtf

I am making a simple parser from RTF to HTML.

I have the following raw RTF:

```
who\\~nursed\\~and
```

According to the RTF specification \~ is the keyword for a non-breaking space.

The end of a keyword is marked by a Delimiter which is defined as follows:

> A space. This serves only to delimit a control word and is ignored in subsequent processing.
>
> A numeric digit or an ASCII minus sign (-), which indicates that a numeric parameter is associated with the control word. The subsequent digital sequence is then delimited by any character other than an ASCII digit (commonly another control word that begins with a backslash). The parameter can be a positive or negative decimal number. The range of the values for the number is nominally –32768 through 32767, i.e., a signed 16-bit integer. A small number of control words take values in the range −2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647 (32-bit signed integer). These control words include \binN, \revdttmN, \rsidN related control words and some picture properties like \bliptagN. Here N stands for the numeric parameter. An RTF parser must allow for up to 10 digits optionally preceded by a minus sign. If the delimiter is a space, it is discarded, that is, it’s not included in subsequent processing.
>
> **Any character other than a letter or a digit. In this case, the delimiting character terminates the control word and is not part of the control word.** Such as a backslash “\”, which means a new control word or a control symbol follows.

As i understand it, the highlighted part above, is the rule used in this particular instance. But if that is the case, then my parser would read until the ~ sign, and conclude that since this is not a letter or a digit, it is not part of the keyword.
This currently results in the following output:

> who~nursed~and

I have the following code for reading a keyword:

```
    public GetKeyword(index: number): KeywordSet {
        var keywordarray: string[] = [];
        var valuearray: string[] = [];
        index++;
        while (index < this.m_input.length) {
            var remainint = this.m_input.substr(index);
            //Keep going until we hit a delimiter
            if (this.m_input[index] == " ") {
                index++;
                break;
            } else if (this.IsNumber(this.m_input[index])) {
                valuearray.push(this.m_input[index]);
            } else if (this.IsDelimiter(this.m_input[index])) {
                break;
            } else keywordarray.push(this.m_input[index]);
            index++;
        }
        var value: number = null;
        if (valuearray.length > 0) value = parseInt(valuearray.join(""));
        var keywordset = new KeywordSet(keywordarray.join(""), index, value);
        return keywordset;
    }

    private IsDelimiter(char: string): boolean {
        if (char == "*" || char == "'") return false;
        return !this.IsLetterOrDigit(char);
    }
```

When GetKeyword() reaches "~" it recognises it as a delimiter, and stops reading, resulting in an empty keyword as return value.

I do not have an AST constructed for this. Don't think it is necessary for this?

Comment: I removed my answer, since i misread your question. If you want help with the parsing you will need to supply code snippets of what you are doing, otherwise we cannot help you. Furthermore, you might want to update your answer with the comment you gave on my answer. That the "\\~" is interpreted as an unknown keyword followed by a "~". When you are parsing this, do you build the complete AST or are you simply spitting on the '\' delimiter?

Answer (score 0):

The quote in your question describes the syntax of an entity called `control word` but the `\~` is actually a different entity called `control symbol`. Control symbols have a different syntax:

> **Control Symbol**
>
> A *control symbol* consists of a backslash followed by a single, non-alphabetical character. For example, \~ (backslash tilde) represents a non-breaking space. Control symbols do not have delimiters, i.e., a space following a control symbol is treated as text, not a delimiter.

See page 9 of [Rich Text Format (RTF) Specification, version 1.9.1](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=10725).